# Why div 100% width doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm learning CSS and finding that it's not always so intuitive (welcome to webdev, I guess). :)

In an attempt to make a simple, static progress bar, I use the HTML file below:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <table border='1' cellspacing='0'>
      <tr>
        <td>Sample Cell</td>
        <td>
          <!-- This is meant to be a progress bar -->
          <div style="background-color: #0a0; width: 20%;">
            <div style="text-align: center; width: 300px;">
              Text Here!
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I get this:

[image: Progress Bar]

which is good, except for the fact that the width of the second column is fixed. But if I go ahead and change `width: 300px` to `width: 100%`, the text instead goes into the green box, rather than the whole table cell.

How can I "fill" the table cell with the text, without imposing a specific length restriction?

Comment: I'm confused, what is the end goal?

Comment: I second the confusion...100% does not equal amount in pixels, it is what it is.

Comment: don't you need a table with to use a percent?

Comment: @JohnathanKong - no as he has placed the size on the actual div element.  Its parent is another div element.

Comment: I wouldn't put divs inside table cells.  It's sloppy, unnecessary, and they're both block level elements.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to center the text in the cell, pretty much, while still having the progress bar shown correctly.

Comment: @josh: Again, the end goal is to get exactly what I'm getting right now in terms of layout, but **without** setting a fixed width.
@JonH: Yeah I guess my trouble is that I want my text and my green div to overlap (independently) inside the table cell... hope that makes more sense?

Comment: @Sparky: I don't know about the unnecessary part (if I didn't need a progress bar I wouldn't be making one :P), but if it's sloppy, then what's a better way to display a progress bar in a table cell?

Comment: @Mehrdad:  "unnecessary" - as in, you don't need to contain divs inside table cells.

Comment: @Sparky: If you know a better way of showing a progress bar in a table cell (other than embedding an image), I'm all for it...

Comment: @Mehrdad:  I'm unfamiliar with the details of your project... why you need a table at all, etc.

Comment: @Sparky: Yeah unfortunately if I share the details I might get fired, so sorry. :P If you don't like the assumption that I need a table then sorry, not much I can do about it right now... though I'd appreciate it if you avoided erasing the entire question. :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By placing your text div inside (as a child of) your colored div, you're telling HTML that you want the text to appear inside the colored div. So a width of 100% on the inner div means whatever the width of its parent div is, which you have set to 20%.

**EDIT: added code**
**EDIT: updated code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #bar{
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }

        #progress{
            background-color: #0a0;
            width: 20%;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        #progress_text{
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            z-index:1;
        }
        .progress_cell{

        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border='1' cellspacing='0'>
      <tr>
        <td>Sample Cell</td>
        <td class="progress_cell">
          <div id="bar">
             <!-- This is meant to be a progress bar -->
             <div id="progress">
               &nbsp;
             </div>
             <div id="progress_text">
                  Text Here! Text Here! But it's really long, and it's going to overflow ...
             </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Ken: That makes a lot of sense, but I guess now my question is: How can I put the text and the green div at the same level, so that they overlap?

Comment: You'll want to use the property position:absolute; to pull the element out of the normal HTML flow. You'll also need to add a position:relative on one of it's parent elements.

Comment: Using position:relative on one of it's parents (probably the table cell) will tell the html that it should be positioned absolutely, but relative to the element marked 'relative'.

Comment: @Ken: It looked as if it would work, but it still doesn't turn out right -- the text goes on top of the gray background, but the green goes *outside* the table, *under* the cell. :\

Comment: so we wrapped the entire bar in a div with position:relative. Then I pulled the text out of the progress indicator and put it as a sibling, instead of a child. Adding position:absolute to the text means it will be positioned absolutely within the closest ancestor that is position:relative;. The last piece is to add top:0px to the text, to tell it where you want it.

Comment: @Ken: [Slight problem](http://jsfiddle.net/cN3bC/)... the text needs to always be in the table (the table needs to adjust as needed)

Comment: i updated the code. i made the bar position:absolute instead of the text. This means that the text will influence the cell size. Because of this I also had to add some z-indexes to tell the code which piece should be on top, and you can only use z-index on a positioned element, so I made the text position:relative also. http://jsfiddle.net/cN3bC/7/

Comment: @Ken: [After a little modification](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7xtW/) it seems to do what I need, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Also, you should really consider using style sheets. It will make your life a lot easier if you ever need to go back and change the colors. :) Cheers! -Ken

Comment: @Ken: Haha yeah I'll probably end up doing that, right now I'm just more comfortable with having a single file & syntax, but when it gets more complex/repetitive I'll probably use style sheets. Also, another question: It seems like the div doesn't resize itself to fit into the cell, if the cell is larger than normal (because of *another* cell in the row). If the cell is too large because its own text is too long, the div *does* resize, but if the cell is too large because of something else, it doesn't. Any idea how to fix that by any chance? (See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7xtW/3/).)

Comment: set widths on your table cells. each browser is going to interpret how it should assign the widths of table cells based on the amount of text in each cell in the entire column. you can use percentages for the widths if you don't want to set them to a pixel value. but you have to tell it something about how you want the width, or it's going to do whatever it wants.

Comment: hmm. not really sure on that one. according to http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=15423 : "2) TD's do not report their height for percentage calculations - so the answer is NO on doing what you want." Not sure what to tell you there... Put a border around the progress bar to make it look like you meant it to be that size? Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

here's your intro to html / css.  thank me when you get my bill ;).  first ... tables are for tabular data.  not layout second ...

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:50%;
    width:900px;
    height:500px;
    margin:0px auto 0px -450px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#369;
}

#box_1 {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

and here's the html ...

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="box_1">
                <p>stuff</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

hope this helps get you started

Comment: Yes, my data *is* tabular, but it happens that the last column shows progress, so I'm showing a progress bar there too. :) I'll give this a try, thanks.

Comment: you might try using a span instead of div inside the table. where the outer <td> is 100% and the span is whatever %

Comment: @b_dubb: I tried `<span style="background-color: #ccc; width: 100%">` immediately inside `<td>`, but as soon as I say `100%`, it just scales to the text width, not the cell width.

Comment: you want the text INSIDE the progress bar?  why not on two separate lines?

Answer (score 0):

If you set width to %,it will take the width of their parent element.In your case.the div takes the width of the parent element i.e td

Comment: Yeah but isn't the parent's width the table column width? Why isn't it centered relative to the column if I say `100%`? That's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution (I think?)

http://jsfiddle.net/tT2HR/

Comment: Thanks! But the `valign=top` is cheating -- what if I want it centered?