# `vertical-align: middle` doesn't do what I expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I am in a table cell in a apply the CSS rule `vertical-align: middle;` to that cell then all the text centers vertically in the cell.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            I am vertically centered text!
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, if I apply this to another element it functions differently or not at all. For example:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 400px; vertical-align: middle;">
    I am not vertically centered, but I wish I was :(
</div>
```

But then if I apply it to an image tag then it adjusts how the image is oriented with other inline elements.

[Here is a jsfiddle with examples of all these scenarios.](http://jsfiddle.net/Chevex/7FYBa/)

My question is, how can I accomplish vertical center alignment within a simple DIV just like the way it behaves in a table cell?

Comment: `display: table-cell` (half kidding)

Comment: @Zack This works, but not if the `DIV` is `position: absolute`. Any idea why?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/Chevex/7FYBa/2/ for example.

Comment: This article tells it all: [Understanding vertical-align](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

Comment: @AlexFord Applying `vertical-align:center` and `position:absolute` to the same CSS box doesn't make sense.  `position:absolute` means "place the box exactly as specified by `left:` etc" so vertical alignment isn't allowed to move the box anymore.

Comment: @Zack It does make sense in that I am trying to vertically center the text within the DIV, not the DIV itself. Jonathan Payne's answer does what I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center a div without knowing the height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283138/center-a-div-without-knowing-the-height) and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: table-cell` to your div.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7FYBa/20/

```
<div class="outer" style="position:absolute;">
    <div class="inner" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">
        I am not vertically centered, but I wish I was :(
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. This is useful in most situations, but in my usage I need to have the div with `position: absolute` and then the centering stops. http://jsfiddle.net/Chevex/7FYBa/2/ Any ideas?

Comment: If you're absolutely positioning your DIV, then you (virtually) won't ever be able to vertically center it in the surrounding element.

Comment: @AlexFord You can wrap it in a parent div, and absolute position that instead. I updated my answer and fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

But of course. Vertical centering is pretty funky in CSS.

I'd suggest you read up on some of the vertical centering techniques out there. Different elements and considerations equate to different methods. [Here's an article I'd suggest](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/7FYBa/30/

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` works for none-table-elements when you increase the `line-height`.

```
#elem {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

But of course layouting is not that easy using `line-height`.